# Be influenced or get influenced

Tags: verbs

Is it **be** or **get**?

Ex.

> ''self-discipline is key, and this is how you are not going to **be influenced** by people around you easily.''

Or

> ''self-discipline is key, and this is how you are not going to **get influenced** by people around you easily.''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

".....you're not going to get/be influenced by........"

You can use either get or be, without any difference in meaning.

However the former (get) is usually used in informal English.

Answer (score 2):

Be influenced makes more sense but allow me to suggest a sentence.

> Self discipline is key; it is how you will prevent yourself from being easily influenced by those around you.

Comment: Hello thx for your suggestion. However, the 'those' pronoun that you've just used can be misinterpreted(instead of just using 'people') can't it?

Comment: People and those are interchangable in this context:) use which one you prefer, but it's smoother to say those.